# How to find value from matrix

Tags: matlab

Let say I have a matrix

```
A=[0.8 0.9 0.7 0.5 0.3 0.8 0.2 0.1];    % 8 points
```

where `A` come from logical `1` from `B`

```
B=[1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1];
```

As I want to find location `C` that satisfies

```
C=find(A<0.6 & A>0.35)
```

where the ans is `C=4`. My question is how to get the true location in `B=8`?

Comment: i got 1. but i want to find the location

Comment: I still cannot get the picture how `A` and `B` are connected and what do you mean by **true location in B=8**. There is no element in `B` equal to `8`, neither in `A`.

Comment: actually this is part of the cross validation process using logical values. the count of original value is equal to the count in B. Using logical 1, only A is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you do not have the indices stored away somewhere, I cannot see that you have much of a choice here.

```
tmp = find(B);
idx = tmp(C);
```

In case you actually want to use this mapping more than once, I would suggest that you store the indices instead of a binary vector. This will also be more memory efficient in case the binary vector is sparse (or not a boolean vector), since you will need less entries.

In case you also need the binary vector, you should store both in case memory allows. When I have done this kind of mapping in Matlab I have actually used both a binary vector (a mask) and an index vector. This have saved me from first mapping the mask to index and then index to filtered position (so to say, skipping the `tmp = find(B); idx = tmp(C);` part every time and go directly to `idx = allIdx(C)`).

Comment: dear patrik, i get error for the function idx=allIdx(C) .is it a build in function?

Comment: @Acobot `allIdx` is not a function. This was meant as an example of the vector where you store the ones in B `allIdx = find(B);`. The first 2 lines will do the trick and  `allIdx = find(B);` will relieve you from repeating these lines everytime you want to use the indices from B. This does somehow imply that this is some kind of model information, which does not go out of scope at the end of the function (for example that you use a struct as input and output).

Comment: thanx patrik, i got it

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the index in B

```
A=[0.8 0.9 0.7 0.5 0.3 0.8 0.2 0.1];
B=[1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1];
C=find(A<0.6 & A>0.35);
temp=0;
for i=1:size(B,2)
    temp=temp+B(i);
    if(temp==C)
        break;
    end
end
locationB=i;
locationB
```

Comment: Why you use `i` as counter when it is reserved for imaginary unit?

Comment: @Crowley `i` or `j` or `1i` can be used for imaginary unit. That doesn't mean it can't be used. `1i` is actually reserved.

Comment: I've tried to overwrite `i` and evaluate `3+5*1i` and there's no interference. So you're right. Still I'll be careful because overwriting `i` and using complex number in form `3+5*i` will cause unexpected and hardly traceable errors.

Comment: @Crowley If you use it like `3+5i`, the  `i` will act as imaginary unit. But if it is `3+5*i`. Then it will be considered as a variable. So I don't think it will be an issue.

Comment: Problem is, that `i` and `j` are preallocated as imaginary units and are not protected against overwriting. `1i=5;` throws error, `i=5;` does not. Try `clear i,3+5*i,i=2;3+5*i`.

Comment: @Crowley First of all you cant do this `1i=5;`. Because variable name cant start with a number.

Comment: @Crowley this discussion should be held [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab). However the `i` and `j` are **not** reserved words. They are actually functions (try `i(), help i, edit i`) and as such they can be overridden. Anyway `1i` is reserved for the imaginary unit (note that the **1** prevents it from being overridden). Note that I am not stating whether or not to iterate with `i` and `j`. This discussion should be held in the provided link instead.